# How to vertical align text bottom for long table in XSL-FO

Tags: alignment, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have long (2 pages and more) table with two columns and would like to put `Right Column Cell` at the end of table. For 1st row I've made this:

```xml
<fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>Row 1</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell display-align="after" number-rows-spanned="20">
        <fo:block>Right Column Cell</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

But in resulted PDF I get the text at bottom of first page, but not table:
[image]

XSL-FO processor: Apache FOP v2.5.

My example .fo:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master margin-right="2cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-top="2cm" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" master-name="page">
            <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block font-size="36pt">
                <fo:table width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
                    <fo:table-column column-width="30%"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="70%"/>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 1</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell display-align="after" number-rows-spanned="20">
                                <fo:block>Right Column Cell</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 2</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 3</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 4</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 5</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 6</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 7</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 8</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 9</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 10</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 11</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 12</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 13</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 14</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 15</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 16</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 17</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 18</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 19</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>Row 20</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>                            
                        </fo:table-row>                     
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

What did I do wrong? Or it's FOP bug?

Answer (score 1):

If 'Row 20' and 'Right Column Cell' will always be the same number of lines (or if 'Row 20' may also be more lines than 'Right Column Cell), then you could just put 'Right Column Cell' in the second column of row 20.

If it's not that simple, then you might be out of luck. I tried your sample with AH Formatter V7.0 and got 'Right Column Cell' at the bottom of the first page.

If you were using AH Formatter, then you could use `axf:repeat-cell-content-at-break` (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v70e/ahf-ext.html#axf.repeat-cell-content-at-break) to repeat the content, though that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but, unfortunately, the right cell may has a long text.